# Return documents created since midnight

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to find all document's created since midnight, regardless of the users timezone. If the users on Pacific time, it should show all their documents since midnight Pacific. Same with Eastern time.

I'm on Eastern time and this works for me:

```
var d = new Date();
    var midnight = d.setHours(0,0,0,0); // last midnight

    var count = Items.find({
      username: Meteor.user().username,
      createdAt: { $gt: midnight }
    }).count();
```

But my client is on CST and it doesn't work for him. It instead shows documents created since like 10pm or 11pm CST the previous day. So this seems like a timezone issue for me.

Comment: have you tried `setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`?

Comment: Is this a **client-side** or **server-side** code? If it's **client-side,** the timezone of the users don't matter; **the timezone of  the server is what counts.** If it's client-side, well, the time will be different

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD I believe it is client-side, because both of the user's time zones where different

Comment: Are the dates stored in the ''Items" normalized to some offset? Do you change your "$gt: mignight" to the same normalization?

Comment: @stephenthedev also btw, have you tried the `setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` yet?

Comment: @MarvinSmit I'm storing the date like this: `createdAt: new Date().getTime()`

Comment: @ThePixelBug you mean like `var midnight = d.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: @stephenthedev yes I do. I would like to see if that works...

Comment: @stephenthedev Silly question, but how are creation dates stores in your MongoDB? Are they the relative local creation dates relative to each user's time zone? or UTC dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this is a client-side issue only (all of the times are stored in UTC on the server) then you can get the UTC adjusted time for midnight of the users current timezone by doing the following:

```
var now = new Date();
var midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var midnight_utc = new Date(Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()));
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbk1vo0j/1/
For example, for my current time zone (eastern) I get the following values for now, midnight, and midnight_utc (when printing the Date objects using the toLocaleString() method):

```
3/30/2015, 3:06:39 PM
3/30/2015, 12:00:00 AM
3/29/2015, 8:00:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

try `setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`. It gets the Coordinated Universal Time that should be the same for every user.

Comment: Maybe, but unless the users are both on GMT, it won't be "midnight" for either of them.

Comment: This didnt work. It detected midnight for the user on CST when it was really 10pm in that local zone.

Comment: @RobG can you explain why that is?

Comment: There is a flaw on using the proposed method, and can lead to incorrect results. You may use the "Edit" option on your answer to improve.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement so I did used following method,

1. Created function to map datetime to _id
2. used that id to get my data.

Function that I am using is

```
function objectIdWithTimestamp(timestamp){
    // Convert string date to Date object (otherwise assume timestamp is a date)
    if (typeof(timestamp) == 'string') { timestamp = new Date(timestamp); }
    // Convert date object to hex seconds since Unix epoch
    var hexSeconds = Math.floor(timestamp/1000).toString(16);
    // Create an ObjectId with that hex timestamp
    var constructedObjectId = ObjectId(hexSeconds + "0000000000000000");
    return constructedObjectId
}
```

using it

```
db.collection.find({_id:{$gte:objectIdWithTimestamp(Y/m/d H:i:s)}})
```

Answer (score 1):

I will advice you try [moment](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) library and resolve the time zone problem. Where ever client code is getting executed, get its last midnight time, convert it to UTC time & then easily retrieve the information from MongoDb. Few moment library usage example, for more detail [refer here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

```
var str = "2013-12-01"
moment.tz(str, "America/Los_Angeles").format(); // 2013-06-01T00:00:00-07:00
moment.tz(str, "America/New_York").format();    // 2013-06-01T00:00:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 1):

## Minutes since midnight

You can get the minutes since midnight from the user's perspective. Try using it to query the server for changes since x minutes ago.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
var now = d.getTime();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var midnight = d.getTime();
var minutes_ago = Math.floor((now-midnight) / (60 * 1000));
console.log(minutes_ago);
```

output:

```
Date {Thu Apr 02 2015 16:12:54 GMT-0700 (PDT)}
972
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var d = new Date();
var midnight = d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0); // last midnight everywhere

var count = Items.find({
  username: Meteor.user().username,
  createdAt: { $gt: midnight }
}).count();
```